# writing characters to char string, character added, but it is not there (C)

Tags: arrays, c, char

I have a char string, and I need write it into another char string with some modifications

```
    char mem[32];
    char request[16] = "b44849";


    if (request[0] == 'b') {            
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {                
                if (i < 8) {
                    mem[i] = '-';
                    }
                else {
                    if (i < (strlen(request) + 8)) {
                        mem[i] = request[i-7];
                    }
                    else {
                    mem[i] = '+';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The rule is that first 8 characters in **mem** have to be '-', i need to strip the first character of **request**, add remaining of **request** on top of **mem**, and when you have written all of **request** into **mem**, write '+' until the loop ends (at i = 16)

So I would need example above to be:

```
printf("%s\n", mem);
// should yield --------44849+++
// i.e. fill first 8 with minuses, then write request without first char, and then finish with pluses
```

Yet my result is:

```
printf("%s\n", mem);
//--------44849
// and no more pluses
```

What's stranger that the pluses are still there:

```
printf("%c\n", mem[13]);
printf("%c\n", mem[14]);
printf("%c", mem[15]);
// prints:
// (empty character)
// +
// +
```

meaning the characters are still there somehow?
Thank you.

Comment: You have a simple off by one error.  In this case, `request[6]`  is the null terminator, and you are copying it into `mem`.  You want to iterate from 8 to 12 (eg `i < strlen(request) + 8 - 1`, but don't compute `strlen` in the loop.  Grab a pointer to the end and iterate to it.  It's a better idiom.)  Or perhaps you want to index `mem[i] = request[i-8];`

Comment: that was indeed an issue, thank you kind stranger

Comment: Tip: Well formatted code helps focus the issue.  Use an  [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) with an auto-format feature to 1)  improve format, 2) save time.